# C++ unit test for testing performance (synthetic benchmark)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, benchmarking

is there any library just like unit testing library, but instead of testing for correctness, its testing the performance of such functions, the output is execution time, cpu instruction count, performance variance, cache-miss, etc..

Comment: This former SO question might be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606306/performance-testing-utilities-for-c

Answer (score 2):

I use [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for performance profiling. They certainly work on Linux and you can pretty much do all the things you mention.

Comment: I doubt that is enough. Have you used CPPUNIT? I expect he wants a framework in which he can say set up a suite of test-cases, each of which says *this* operation must take no more than *this* amount of time.